# Mac being hacked? Failed login attempts not by me

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, password, login, hacking

A couple days ago I opened my MacBook Pro (2015) and it didn’t ask for the password and automatically opened up to my desktop. This shouldn’t have happened since I set my Mac to ask for password 5 minutes after falling asleep. Nobody in my family touched my Mac in-between the sessions. I am not using an Apple Watch, and currently run the latest version of Catalina.

I used this log to look for failed login attempts to see if someone was remotely hacking into my laptop: `log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication failed")' --style syslog --last 1d`

I saw that there was a failed login as my laptop was closed, and asleep (laptop was asleep according to the logs). Here are the two failed login attempts 7 minutes before I got on my computer.

> 2020-07-16 20:03:34.130054-0500  localhost opendirectoryd[147]: (PlistFile) [com.apple.opendirectoryd:auth] Authentication failed for  with ODErrorCredentialsInvalid

> 2020-07-16 20:03:43.252307-0500  localhost opendirectoryd[147]: (PlistFile) [com.apple.opendirectoryd:auth] Authentication failed for  with ODErrorCredentialsInvalid

I continued to look at the logs and saw that there were failed login attempts when I was sleeping. My computer was asleep aswell.

> 020-07-18 00:36:56.364015-0500  localhost opendirectoryd[147]: (PlistFile) [com.apple.opendirectoryd:auth] Authentication failed for  with ODErrorCredentialsInvalid

> 2020-07-18 00:37:05.042097-0500  localhost opendirectoryd[147]: (PlistFile) [com.apple.opendirectoryd:auth] Authentication failed for  with ODErrorCredentialsInvalid

Could someone explain what is happening? Is someone trying to remotely hack into my computer? And what could’ve caused my Mac to not ask for my password after it had been asleep for 40+ minutes? Could it have just been a glitch or something else?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The most likely think that comes to mind is a password-guessing attack against a network service on your Mac. Do you have Remote Login or any of the other services in the Sharing pane in System Preferences turned on? How is your Mac connected to the Internet (specifically, are you behind any sort of firewall)?

Comment: Is it set to ask for a password at restart?

Comment: This is conflicting - you can’t have a failed user account  login, but have have an authenticated session meaning your desktop is open without logging in.  ODE is OpenDirectory which could be any number of accounts.  Assuming this is a home computer (you mention family), i would start looking at what accounts you have linked to this Mac/user account (i.e. iCloud, Mail, Social media, etc.). Start with rebooting then disable those accounts do you still Have an  issue?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I do not have Remote Login turned on, and my Mac is connected to the internet via normal wifi. And the firewall is turned on in my Mac settings.

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, my Mac asks for a password when I restart. However, this has been happening for multiple days throughout the day.

Comment: Update: I turned off my wifi and bluetooth last night, and I still got two failed login attempts at 1 a.m (ten seconds apart). Could this mean this is some sort of local computer issue or does it not matter that the wifi/bluetooth was off? @Allan

Comment: It sounds like an account (Mail for example, just guessing) might be trying to authenticate, but can't make a connection.  Assuming you don't have Ethernet connected, if there's no connection a "hacker" can't even connect to make a failed attempt.

Comment: @Allan Another update: These failed attempts happen like twice during night when the wifi is off, but mainly happen a couple seconds after I login and during usage. Is there anything I can do to further isolate the cause?

Comment: I just ran this on my Mac (clean install of Catalina) and I get them as well.  I've got this machine and my network locked down tighter than a drum so there's no hacking going on.  This looks normal.

Comment: @Allan so you are also getting random failed login attempts throughout the day? Just wanted to make sure that is what you were referring to.

Comment: Yes.  And to triple check, I booted an old MacBook (no battery) disabled WiFi so it was isolated from everything and it too had those failed logins.  It's not someone trying to hack you.